# Why importing a specific function is not working?

Tags: python, string, built-in

I am interested in importing a specific function from a builtin module, however this raises errors. This is what I would ideally like to do:

```py
from string._string import formatter_parser
# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'string._string'; 'string' is not a package
```

I tried doing it differently, but it also raises error:

```py
from string import _string.formatter_parser
# SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The only thing that works is:

```py
from string import _string
# can later use _string.formatter_parser downstream
```

Comment: Why do you assume there is something like ``string._string`` in the first place? CPython has a ``_string`` module, but it's not guaranteed to always be there.

Comment: If you want ``_string.formatter_parser``, that's just ``from _string import formatter_parser``. Caveat as above applies – there is no guarantee that the ``_string`` module exists, or that it contains what you expect.

Comment: Thank you, @MisterMiyagi. Could you post this as answer (ideally with some comment on how one could identify the correct import name, in this case `_string`)? I will accept it then.

Comment: I was just guessing based on the contradicting content of the question. The question does not seem searchable for people with the same problem, and an answer wouldn't be much else than "if you want X, import X" – I doubt that would help future readers.